# Codeigniter URI segment has "/" embeded in the value

Tags: php, codeigniter

What's the best way to use a URI segment that has a "/" embedded in the value? 
for example, i'm passing a port number that looks like "abc1/1".

Thank you.

Comment: use query strings. I don't recommend concatenating two variables but that should work. Again don't recommend the latter

Comment: does it have to be `/` why not use a url friendly character and then do the parsing in the  receving php script?

Comment: @shawndreck, the value is not set by me.

Comment: can you post the url? and if not do you know in what the segment number? and if not, are they comming at the last all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nice question BTW,**

There are many ways to solve your problem. but what I prefer is to use:

```
$this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
```

I assumed the following url for your case:

```
http://localhost/nearest/nearest/index.php/welcome/testUri/x/1/abc1/1/gg
```

so you can do this in your controller:

```
$array= $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3); // getting from third segment and after
var_dump($array);
```

which will output:

```
array (size=3)
  'x' => string '1' (length=1)
  'abc1' => string '1' (length=1) //here's your argument combined as key => value
  'gg' => boolean false
```

so simply you can get your segment then using this **"key, value"** array.

Comment: @that's exactly what my url looks like.  thanks for this solution.  I'll give it a try!